# How to pass object properties to a function from object itself?

Tags: javascript, oop, javascript-objects

I want to pass an object property to a global function and want to save return value in a new object property .
What I tried:

```
var Tools = {
     id : "tools" ,
     key : myfunc(this.id)      //I also tried Tools["id"] and id .
};
```

Here is the function:

```
function myfunc(tmp){
     return tmp;
}
```

I want to use `Tools.key` not `Tools.key()` that's why I'm not using following code:

```
key : function(){ 
     return myfunc(this.id);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you might want to do:

```
var tools = {
    id: 7,
    get key() { 
        var key = 'Key is ' + this.id; // Do something with this.id
        return key;
    },
};

tools.key; // "Key is 7"
```

You should read [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) to learn and understand more

*Notice that I removed the capital 'T' from tools: since it is not a function that should be used as a constructor, it should not begin with a capital letter.*

Comment: That would not be very convenient unless `tools` is a unique instance, in which case you might as well set `tool.id`and compute the key once and for all.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to get uninitialized property of the object (id). At the moment of creating Tools object id property of it isn't set yet, that's why you're getting undefined there.

You should store Id in variable and pass to your function and property, or create a class Tools and than pass an Id to constructor.

```
var Tool = function(id) {
    return { id: id, key: myFunc(id) };
}
var myTool = Tool(55);
myTool.key // will return 55
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you don't want to recompute the key each time you access it, so the `get` solution seems a bit inefficient to me.

The second solution avoids unnecessary computations, but does not take full advantage of the object mechanism.

I would rather do something like this:

```
var Tool = function (id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.key = myFunc (id);
    return this;
}
```

this way you actually make `id` and `key` attributes of the `Tool` object, instead of returning a generic object with the same fields.

If you want to add class methods later, you will see the advantage.

Assume you define a method like this:

```
Tool.prototype.getCash = function (sum) {
    if (!checkKey (this.key)) callTheCops();
    return sum;
}
```

If you create a `Tool` instance using a constructor that returns an unnamed structure like
`{ id: id , key: myFunc(key) };`
with something like
`var tool = Tool (123);`,
the `tool` variable will not inherit the `getCash()` method and you'll be stuck with a structure that won't know anything about getting cash.

With the above constructor, you can create a class instance like so:
`var tool =`**`new`**`Tool (123);`
and do whatever the class allows with it.